@react-native/popup-menu-android throws Unresolved reference: libs on Android build RN 0.75.3
I upgraded my project to 0.75.3 with no problems, but then after replacing the old UIManager.showPopupMenu with the new lib @react-native/popup-menu-android, the build throws this:
Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installDevDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 -PreactNativeArchitectures=x86_64
e: file:///C:/Users/jvito/Development/soccerskills-app/node_modules/@react-native/popup-menu-android/android/build.gradle.kts:10:9: Unresolved reference: libs e: file:///C:/Users/jvito/Development/soccerskills-app/node_modules/@react-native/popup-menu-android/android/build.gradle.kts:11:9: Unresolved reference: libs FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * Where: Build file 'C:\Users\jvito\Development\soccerskills-app\node_modules\@react-native\popup-menu-android\android\build.gradle.kts' line: 10 * What went wrong: Script compilation errors: Line 10: alias(libs.plugins.android.library) ^ Unresolved reference: libs Line 11: alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.android) ^ Unresolved reference: libs 2 errors

This is the build.gradle.kts from the lib
node_modules/@react-native/popup-menu-android/android/build.gradle.kts
plugins {
  id("com.facebook.react")
  alias(libs.plugins.android.library)
  alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.android)
}

android {
  compileSdk = libs.versions.compileSdk.get().toInt()
  buildToolsVersion = libs.versions.buildTools.get()
  namespace = "com.facebook.react.popupmenu"

  defaultConfig { minSdk = libs.versions.minSdk.get().toInt() }

  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
  }
}

kotlin {
  jvmToolchain(17)
  explicitApi()
}

dependencies {
  // Build React Native from source
  implementation(project(":packages:react-native:ReactAndroid"))
}

I tried manually linking the library but it also didn't work, haven't found any workarounds or any issue related on the react-native repos.

did you manage to fix it by any chance?
